# Click through transparency in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, transparency

I am having issues with overlaying divs with transparency and being able to click on both layers in Chrome (but not IE).

In my search for answers I found the following example to illustrate:
http://www.searchlawrence.com/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements.html

The source for that page is commented to explain about transparency.

If I view this page in IE I can highlight (ie interact) both the text in the box("Here is a div with...") AND the text at the top ("This DIV is overlayed on...").  However, when I open the same page in Chrome, I cannot select the text at the top.

This highlights the issue I am having in using iframes which contains links, but I also want the page containing the iframe to also allow links to be clicked.  The transparanecy works in Chrome in as much as I can see both sets of links, but can only click those on the top layer (ie the iframe).  The top iframe allows me to see what is behind but not interact with it.

I know about pointer-events:none however, that then stops the links on the iframe.  I can basically get it working on the background html OR the overlying iframe but not both!

Hope this all makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution specifically for chrome is using the css:
`div#parent, div#parent div {pointer-events:none;}`

meaning Div, and all children div as well should enable clicking through.

I found the solution here:
[Click through transparency in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935898/click-through-transparency-in-chrome)